# Why doesn't the south part for the border layout show up?

Tags: java

I've tried different methods to fix this, but apparently nothing works. Because I am new to java I actually don't know if there's something wrong with my code. 
I've tried setting the size of the text area that is supposed to go into the SOUTH part of the border layout, but the size is still to small to see.

Anyone know of a solution?

```
package package1;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleDatabasePanel extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JMenuBar menuBar;

    private JMenu file;

    private JMenuItem save, load, quit;

    private JButton add, undo, find, delete, display;
    private JScrollPane pane;
    private JTable table;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JTextArea tName, tGNum, tGPA, results;
    private JLabel name, gNum, gpa;
    private LinkedList list;

public SimpleDatabasePanel(){
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setTitle("Simple Database");
    //setSize(1000,1000);

    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    file = new JMenu("File");

    quit = new JMenuItem("Quit");
    save = new JMenuItem("Save");
    load = new JMenuItem("Load");

    add = new JButton("Add");
    undo = new JButton("Undo");
    find = new JButton("Find");
    delete = new JButton("Delete");
    display = new JButton("Display");

    tName = new JTextArea();
    tGNum = new JTextArea();
    tGPA = new JTextArea();
    results = new JTextArea(10,20);

    name = new JLabel("Name");
    gNum = new JLabel("G Number");
    gpa = new JLabel("GPA");

    list = new LinkedList();

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 4, 4, 4));

    //frame = new JFrame();
    pane = new JScrollPane();
    pane.setSize(300, 60);
    table = new JTable();
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    menuBar.add(file);

    file.add(save);
    file.add(load);
    file.add(quit);

    panel.add(name);
    panel.add(tName);
    panel.add(undo);
    panel.add(add);
    panel.add(gNum);
    panel.add(tGNum);
    panel.add(find);
    panel.add(delete);
    panel.add(gpa);
    panel.add(tGPA);
    panel.add(display);

    pane.add(results);

    add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(pane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    this.pack();        

    ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();

    file.addActionListener(file.getAction());
    find.addActionListener(listener);
    undo.addActionListener(listener);
    save.addActionListener(this);
    quit.addActionListener(this);
    add.addActionListener(listener);
    load.addActionListener(this);
    delete.addActionListener(listener);
    display.addActionListener(listener);


}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JMenuItem file = (JMenuItem) e.getSource();

    if(file == quit){
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if(file == load){
        String filename = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter File Name: ");
        (list).load(filename);
    }
    if(file == save){
        String filename = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter File Name: ");
        (list).save(filename);
    }



}

private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        if(event.getSource() == add){

        }
        if(event.getSource() == delete){

        }
        if(event.getSource() == display){

        }
        if(event.getSource() == find){

        }
        if(event.getSource() == undo){

        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    SimpleDatabasePanel s =new SimpleDatabasePanel();
    s.setVisible(true);
    s.setResizable(false);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
pane.add(results);
```

to this

```
pane.setViewportView(results);
```

or this

```
pane.getViewport().add(results, null);
```

use  `setViewportView` or `getViewport().add` to set component to `jscrollpane`.also you can pass component (jtextarea ) to constructor of jscrollpane.[read more about jscrollpane here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html)

output

[image]